# CSS positioning and Scaling Image with its bottom origin fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have several background images which are being used to recreate a scene of a person along a horizon line. I want to make it such that the image itself grows but stays at this horizon/baseline.

Here's the html:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row foreground">
    <center>
        <img class="foreground" src="css/images/BandName.png" alt="Planet of the Abts">
        <img class="foreground" src="css/images/AlbumTitle.png" alt="Planet of the Abts">
    </center>
    </div>

    <img id="missSaturn" src="css/images/miss_Saturn.png" alt="">

    <div id="videoDiv">
        <iframe id="video" width="700" height="394" align="center" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qMlyymUYjEM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
html{
height:100%;
width:100%;}

body{
height:100%;
background:url(images/ground2.png) no-repeat,
    url(images/spaceBackground.jpg)no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position:0 300px,0 0 ;}


iframe{
margin:0 auto;
box-shadow: 5px 5px yellow;
max-width: 100%;}

.container-fluid{
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding-left:0;
padding-right:0;}

#video {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
min-width:300px;
margin-top: 300px;
margin-bottom: 30px;}

.row{
margin: 0 auto;}

#missSaturn{
z-index:-1;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width:80%;
position:fixed;
transform-origin:bottom 50%;}

.foreground{
z-index: 100;}

@media all and (min-width:300px){
#missSaturn{
    top:30%;}}

@media all and (min-width:400px){
#missSaturn{
    top:200px;
    left:15%;}}

@media all and (min-width:600px){
#missSaturn{
    top:100px;}}

@media all and (min-width:800px){
#missSaturn{
    top:50px;}}
```

Essentially this is what I'm trying to achieve. As the browser/device resizes left to right, the image scales down but with its origin at that baseline.

Image of what I'm trying to achieve

[image: horizon/baseline image background]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try `transform-origin:50% bottom;` instead of `transform-origin:bottom 50%;`. X-axis comes first.

Answer (score 0):

In your css id #missSaturn switch the `transform-origin:bottom 50%` to `transform-origin:50% bottom`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use absolute positioning for that specific element, then combined `top: 50%;` and `transform: translateY(-50%);` could do the trick.

```
center {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20vh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.foreground {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 20%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

You may see the [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/kavare/pen/EjYLQa?editors=110) here.

By this way, the base line for the element would be consistent in different screen sizes, which is always on the middle of the container for that element.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a sticky footer:

- `.top` pushes the bottom div — `.footer` — down with 100% `min-height`. The footer height is subtracted — [using `calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) — making it stick to the bottom of the viewport.
- `.top` is given a centered background image that will scale thanks to the `background-size` property. The `bottom` value will keep it at the bottom of the `.top` div at all times.
- `max-width: 100%` on the iframe allows it to scale down if required

### Working Example

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.top {
  min-height: calc(100% - 394px);
  background: url(http://www.placehold.it/500) center bottom no-repeat;
  background-size: 20%
}
.footer {
  height: 394px;
  background: #F90;
}
iframe {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="top">

</div>

<footer class="footer">
  <iframe id="video" width="700" height="394" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qMlyymUYjEM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</footer>
```